# Windows update error code 86430003 - Security Update for SQL Server 2016 RTM GDR (KB3194716)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update, sql-server-2016

My server is failing to install update KB3194716. I am getting an error code 86430003 from windows update. Server is Windows Server 2012 R2. Windows update is consistently failing to apply this, my update history is a list of these updates with a status of 'cancelled'.

A search for this error code brings up nothing. Anyone know what it means? Or how I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

This error was caused by a pending restart. More information at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/826aef6b-2de3-4993-9fc1-0312f73b0195/windows-update-error-code-86430003-security-update-for-sql-server-2016-rtm-gdr-kb3194716?forum=sqlsecurity